# Get GeometryReader to conform to content height

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a GeometryReader that properly spaces two input fields in .25/.75 proportion.

The issue is that the height of the geometry reader forms a perfect square where the height matches the width.

Is there a way to get the height to conform to the content within?

```
        GeometryReader { geometry in HStack(spacing: 20) {
      MsInputField(fieldInput: $country, placeholder: Text("P"))
        .frame(
          width: geometry.size.width * 0.25
        )
      MsInputField(fieldInput: $phone, placeholder: Text("Phone"), preIcon: "DropDown", postIcon: "DropDown")
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: A `GeometryReader` is a greedy view that takes all of the space that it is given. You haven't posted a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but if you limit the space given, the `GeometryReader` will shrink. But to what end? The purpose of the `GeometryReader` is to let you know the size and position of that space.

Comment: Thank you.  My purpose in this case is to only use geometry reader on the horizontal and ignore the vertical.

Comment: You really can't. It will take all space offered to it. However, it doesn't affect anything by doing so. It just reads the space.

Answer (score -2):

the GeometryReader takes the available space in the parent view so you need to set the width and height for the GeometryReader
or you can set the height and width for the Hstack inside it also

```
    GeometryReader { geometry in HStack(spacing: 20) {
       MsInputField(fieldInput: $country, placeholder: Text("P"))
      .frame(
      width: geometry.size.width * 0.25
       )
      MsInputField(fieldInput: $phone, placeholder: Text("Phone"), 
          preIcon: "DropDown", postIcon: "DropDown")
       }
       }.frame(width:150,height:50,alignment:.center)
```

Comment: Thank you. Fixing the height works, but it does not adapt dynamically to the child content of the frame.  Is there a way to set the frame height to dynamically adjust to the child content?